# How should employees contact their manager instead of engaging IT directly?

Tags: employees, technology

Would anyone be willing to share their written process for employees to engage IT personnel?

We have one IT person and almost 300 employees.  Employees are going directly to him with every request (I need a new monitor), instead of going to their manager for approval.

We want to put a a process in place where employees go to their managers and they filter requests that they approve up.

How can we solve this issue with a process?

Comment: This is really a bit broad now and doesn't have a specific problem, can you [edit] to clarify so it's more answerable?

Comment: Hope I've clarified it!

Comment: I clarified a bit more and reopened it. It's still a bit borderline but thanks for the edit!

Comment: *How can we solve this issue with a process?* Let me fix that for you: **How can we solve this issue? With a process!**

Answer (score 9):

Get a work tracking application and set it up so that nothing goes to a technician until the manager of the submitter approves it. You can also set it up so that certain things don't need approvals. Depends on what you need.  Don't work on anything except what has come through the tracker.

Anyone asks for anything, the response is put in a ticket for that and it will get added to the queue. It is difficult for peopel who are used to helping everyone, to adjust to this, but they will find it easier to get things done as the priorities can be set through the application and people will be able to see how much work there is to do, etc.

Comment: That is the easy part. The hard part is getting the 300 people to start using it. What I found is that a lot of people think there time is to valuable to write tickets. My response to this usaually however was that if it isn't important enough for time to take that time, it isn't important enough for me to work on. Eventually they got it. However being the only IT person and 300 people...goodluck!

Comment: No the hard part is getting the IT guy and his manager to use it and not do anything outside the system.  Once he or she is using this exclusively, then everyone will have to enter tickets or not get the work done. But the manager can't let anyone not even the CEO get by with making requests that are not entered into the system.

Answer (score 5):

> Employee to IT guy: I need a new monitor.
>   IT guy to employee: Sorry, I can't do that without approval from your manager. Please get them to contact me once they've approved your request and I'll get it done.

Problem solved. You probably want to send round some form of communications first letting people know this is the new procedure, but I don't see a need for anything more heavyweight than this.

Comment: That's a good start, but not as good as some sort of task tracking system like Jira, Trello, etc. At some point the company is going to have to hire additional support staff, and at that point it'll be essential to have a tool in place anyway.